# Authenticate with AWS ECR without aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, authentication, amazon-ecr

The canonical way I've seen to authenticate with an ECR repo (for docker) is to use the `aws ecr get-login-password` command https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/registry_auth.html#registry-auth-token

I am in an environment where I'm unable to install the `aws` cli command. Does anyone know of a way to generate this password through an API (like HTTP or SDK)? I assume that since it's done via the AWS CLI, there's an API behind it. However I seem to unable to find any guide or documentation for this.

Comment: There's an API call: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/APIReference/API_GetAuthorizationToken.html

Comment: If you can't use one of the pre-built AWS SDK libraries, then you'll need to read about the request signing process: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signing-aws-api-requests.html

Comment: Just wondering if you may replicate the functionality of aws CLI, why are you not allowed to install the `aws` CLI? It seems to me the same thing between using the CLI that makes the API calls and creating a new CLI that makes the same API calls.

Comment: @RegisterSole excellent question - thanks for asking. I'm building a tool that can be used by others. While we can expect reasonable tools installed, aws cli is not something we wanna assume, and wanna provide the functionality even if it's not.

Answer (score 1):

Almost every Amazon document points us to using the CLI or an SDK, however it is possible to make it work with just API calls.

There are two main challenges to making direct API calls:

1. [Signing AWS API requests](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signing-aws-api-requests.html)

   As of [curl 7.75.0](https://curl.se/mail/archive-2021-02/0006.html) we have the [--aws-sigv4](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#--aws-sigv4) option to handle this nicely.

   It requires a region and service code, as well as a value for the --user arg, where the region and service code need to match the API url, while the values for user depend on your authentication method.

   Example:
   `curl --url 'https://api.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com' --aws-sigv4 "aws:amz:us-east-1:ecr" --user "<user>:<pass>"`

   ECR [public](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/ecr-public.html) and [private](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/ecr.html) endpoints are well documented.
2. The ECR API docs lack some details

- All operations seem to be POST
- All requests require at least an empty json object `{}`
- The Action is passed in the special header `'x-amz-target: SpencerFrontendService.<Action>`
- Use `Content-Type: application/x-amz-json-1.1`